# Find the circle which passes through two points

Tags: circles, analytic-geometry

> Find the equation of a circle which passes through $(4,-3)$ and $(-3,-4)$ with radius $5$.

I tried putting the $x$ and $y$ into the equation $(x-h)^2 + (y-k)^2 = r^2$, but then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: If you know the famous [3-4-5 right-angled triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_right_triangles#Side-based), then you can see immediately that $(0,0)$ is one point which has distance 5 from the given points.

Answer (score 4):

Since we have
$$(4-h)^2+(-3-k)^2=5^2\iff h^2-8h+16+k^2+6k+9=25\tag1$$
$$(-3-h)^2+(-4-k)^2=5^2\iff h^2+6h+9+k^2+8k+16=25$$
subtracting the latter from the former gives you 
$$(-8-6)h+7+(6-8)k-7=0\iff k=-7h.$$
Then, use $(1)$ to get $h=0,1$. So, the answer is the followings :
$$x^2+y^2=25,\ \ (x-1)^2+(y+7)^2=25.$$